# entity_reference field widget as select instead of autocomplete

Tags: 8, entities

Is there a select widget I can use instead of autocomplete for referencing entities? Right now I am using this in my `baseFieldDefinitions` function:

```
->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'settings' => array(
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
      'size' => 60,
      'placeholder' => '',
    ),
  ))
```

but I need to have a select widget instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to change the widget from the field config page. The key used by drupal was `options_select`, so I updated the type to:

```
'type' => 'options_select'
```

Comment: note that the select widget has different settings (actually none I think), so make sure to update that as well. In general, to figure out what options you have, you can always create a field of the same type in the UI (or make it configurable), then export the created view/form display and convert the YAML type + settings back into PHP for your base field definition.